# C++ Failing on "Pure Virtual Function Being Called"

Tags: c++, object, memory-leaks

I am writing some code to remove from an AVL tree. Here is a sample function that helps to do the removal:

```
int AVL::getLargestAndTrim(Node*& currentNode, Node* parentNode) {
    if (currentNode->right == nullptr) {
        int returnData = currentNode->data;
        parentNode->right = currentNode->left;
        delete currentNode;
        return returnData;
    }
    else {
        Node* rightChild = currentNode->right;
        return this->getLargestAndTrim(currentNode->right, currentNode);
    }
}
```

That code keeps failing, with the message "pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception".

Now, if I replace the line

```
return this->getLargestAndTrim(currentNode->right, currentNode);
```

with

```
return this->getLargestAndTrim(rightChild, currentNode);
```

it works fine. How?

**EDIT:** The Node class is defined as:

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node() {}
        Node(int data) : data(data) {}

        ~Node() {}

    private:
        int data = 0;
        Node* left = nullptr;
        Node* right = nullptr;

        int height = 0;

    friend class AVL;
};
```

Comment: It's because you failed to include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what else should I include? To me the only problem is passing the variable `rightChild` to the recursive function or not

Comment: For instance, how is the `Node` class defined?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm edited question with new definition

Comment: The help center article I linked you to: [mcve] - explains what you need to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sequence

```
parentNode->right = currentNode->left;
delete currentNode;
```

is wrong.  Because `currentNode` is a reference to `parentNode->right`, when you make that assignment it changes the value of `currentNode`, then you delete what had been in `currentNode->left` while having a dangling pointer in the tree point to the deleted data.

Later on when the destructor is called for the deleted object you'll get the error.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. So just to clarify, it worked when assigning the variable because I assigned the copy of the variable by reference, but broke otherwise because I was changing the real value?

Comment: @theEpsilon Yes, because when you deleted with the copy it didn't change the tree and you didn't get the double delete.